# Semantic-UI React: How to theme using less variables in a create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, semantic-ui-react

I am using Semantic-UI in my create-react-app project. I am using a custom theme to modify individual components using ThemeProvider, which is working well. 
However I am trying to figure out how to modify the less variables as [described in the semantic-ui documentation](https://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html)

The [react semantic-ui](https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage) documentation doesn't offer much on this.
Any advise?

My Index.js looks roughly like this:

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import mainTheme from './themes/mainTheme'


ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={mainTheme}>
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Edit: to be specific on what I am trying to achieve, I want to change the main font used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across [this tutorial to use a custom theme using sematnic UI and CRA](https://jsramblings.com/2018/03/04/how-to-use-semantic-ui-with-a-custom-theme-in-your-CRA-app.html) which outlines this process perfectly.
It is quiet long process so I'll leave it with just the link.

[Here is the link to the Github repo of the tutorial.](https://github.com/ucorina/semantic-ui-react-theming)

Answer (score 1):

Looking over the [docs](https://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html#sitewide-defaults) you could basically have a `globals` folder in your `theme` folder which contains two optional files: `site.variables` and `site.overrides`. I assume you could override the `@font` variable in said `site.overrides`.

You can see an example of `site.variables` [here](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/example-github/blob/master/semantic/src/themes/github/globals/site.variables).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got the part that I can use the site.overrides file to modify the site.variables. I just don't get how to set it up so it takes my custom site.overrides file when building...

Comment: I believe you have to change the site variable from your theme.config to match the theme you want

Comment: What I meant is, let's say I create a theme.config or site.variables file, where do I tell my built to use this custom file? Can you show an example of the file in which this is specified? (is this in index.js, added to the code I pasted above, or somewhere else?)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer... I don't think you can.

Since you are importing the `.css` file here directly, you are using the compiled stylesheet, so less variables will do you no good. I see one of two ways to solve this issue.

1) Create your own less stylesheet that then imports this libraries' less files. I don't recommend this option since you aren't already using less.

2) Override the font yourself in your own stylesheet. Since you're using styled components, you can use the [`injectGlobal`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#injectglobal) option to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: You can use semantic-ui package for this.
https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage#semantic-ui-package

> Install the full Semantic UI package. Semantic UI includes Gulp build
>   tools so your project can preserve its own theme changes, allowing you
>   to customise the style variables.
>
> Detailed documentation on theming in Semantic UI is provided here.
>
> ```
> $ npm install semantic-ui --save-dev
> ```
>
> After building the project with Gulp, you'll need to include the
>   minified CSS file in your index.js file:
>
> ```
> import '../semantic/dist/semantic.min.css';
> ```

Other approaches: 
One way is to have a theme config as part of your project and have semantic-ui probably in forked git repo and use this config to run a custom build command similar to https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/build-tools.html.

Workflow would be like this. 
Run `gulp build-new`(in forked semantic-ui repo) which takes say argument for `theme.config` path(pointing to your react projects theme path) and places into forked repo then runs `gulp build` generating themed css. you can have the task to even replace complied css into your react project.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the official boilerplate](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/tree/master/examples/webpack3), it contains the preconfigured environment with Webpack3 and examples of theming that follow [theming guide](https://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html).